# Abaqus Scripting: Defining Mesh Seed Area

Tags: python, set, mesh, abaqus, face

I want to assign mesh seeds to selected regions within the the getBoundingBox function but excluding particular areas. How could I do this? What function can i use to deselect some regions? Thank you very much

```
mdb.models['Model-1'].parts['Part-2'].Set(faces=mdb.models['Model-1'].parts['Part-2'].faces.getByBoundingBox(0,0,0,120,96,0), name='Set-4')
```

Comment: I do't think we have any direct method to deselect a particular area. You have to try some work around, may be try to find some property of this area(you  wanna deselect ) with which you can filter

Comment: If its easier to create set(s) for the region you'd like to deselect, you could use Boolean, difference operation on these two sets.